# How to change list value on certain position click?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a list of products in BindableLayout.
When i click on some product i want to change the value of the Active field and "reload" the list [print1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPmEK.png).
There is any way to change the values of the list from the xaml?
What is the best approach?

> MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public List<ProductStatus> ProductList => getProducts();
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = this;
        }
        public List<ProductStatus> getProducts()
        {
            return new List<ProductStatus>
            {
                new ProductStatus { Id="P13", Name = "Product X", Active = false },
                new ProductStatus { Id="P17", Name = "Product Y", Active = false },
                new ProductStatus { Id="P21", Name = "Product Z", Active = true },
            };
        }
    }
    public class ProductStatus
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> MainPage.xaml

```
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout  BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ProductList}">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="1" Padding="20">
                        <StackLayout.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="StackLayout">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Active}" Value="true" TargetType="StackLayout">
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#f0f0f0"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Active}" Value="false" TargetType="StackLayout">
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </StackLayout.Style>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                            <Label.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Label">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Active}" Value="true" TargetType="Label">
                                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="A"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Active}" Value="false" TargetType="Label">
                                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="I"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Label.Style>
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Save"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: is there a reason you're not using a CollectionView or ListView?  Regardless, all you should have to do is add a Tapped gesture to your XAML and update the value in the model, then the UI should refresh itself.  You don't need to reload the entire list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First if you want to display a list,it's better to use `ListView` or `CollectionView`,that's will be more convenient.

If you still want to use `BindableLayout` here,you could add a `TapGestureRecognizer` to your StackLayout.And let your `ProductStatus` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface(for reload the data).

```
public partial class MainPage: ContentPage
{
    public List<ProductStatus> ProductList => getProducts();
    public ICommand TapCommand { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TapCommand = new Command<ProductStatus>(OnTapCommand);
        this.BindingContext = this;
       
    }

    private void OnTapCommand(ProductStatus obj)
    {
        var product = obj;
        product.Active = !obj.Active;
    }

    public List<ProductStatus> getProducts()
    {
        return new List<ProductStatus>
        {
            new ProductStatus { Id="P13", Name = "Product X", Active = false },
            new ProductStatus { Id="P17", Name = "Product Y", Active = false },
            new ProductStatus { Id="P21", Name = "Product Z", Active = true },
        };
    }




}
public class ProductStatus :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private bool active;
    public bool Active {
        set
        {    
                active = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Active");

        }
        get
        {
            return active;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

in your xaml (set `x:Name` to your contentpage,then binding its command):

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Name="root"
         x:Class="EntryCa.MainPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout  BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ProductList}">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="1" Padding="20">
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer   Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.TapCommand,Source ={x:Reference root} }"
        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <StackLayout.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="StackLayout">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Active}" Value="true" TargetType="StackLayout">
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#f0f0f0"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Active}" Value="false" TargetType="StackLayout">
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </StackLayout.Style>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                            <Label.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Label">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Active}" Value="true" TargetType="Label">
                                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="A"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Active}" Value="false" TargetType="Label">
                                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="I"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Label.Style>
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Save"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

the effect like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you that's what i was looking for, any special reason to avoid BindableLayout, performance issues or something?